# CollectionView WilldisplayCell access with identifiers

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I have an iOS app in swift language. I have a CollectionView with three different types of cell based on identifiers name assigned to it.

I want to assign different properties to all three different cell in

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) { }
```

The images below show how identifier names are given to all three cells of a collectionView.
[image]

How can I use this identifier's name in willDisplayCell method to give unique properties to a different kind of cells?

Comment: you can used `cell.reuseIdentifier`

Answer (score 3):

if you want to access your cell's identifier in `willDisplay` then use

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let identifier = cell.reuseIdentifier

        switch identifier {
        case "yourIdentifier1":
           print("operation1")
        case "yourIdentifier2":
            print("operation2")
        case "yourIdentifier3":
            print("operation3")
        default:
            print("operationDefault")
        }
    }
```